# How can I resolve CPU utilisation nearing 100% on IIS

Tags: iis, web-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net, cpu-usage

I have a .net web API application and the required SQL server hosted on an IIS.
The task manager shows 100% CPU utilization most of the time, but memory usage is fine.

How can I analyze and fix what is wrong here?

I have already tried New Relic APM and Debug Diagnostic Tool but got nothing useful.

[image]

Any insight would be really helpful.

Comment: New Relic APM and Debug Diagnostic Tool free ?

Answer (score 3):

Identify what is killing the CPU. I recommend https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool

Identify what is causing this.